# Problem calling Request using RequestBuilder

Tags: gwt

My Code is

```
    String url = "http: gd.geobytes.com/gd?after=-1&variables=GeobytesCountry,GeobytesCity";
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL
            .encode(url));



    try {
        Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                  Couldn't connect to server (could be timeout, SOP
                  violation, etc.)
            }

            public void onResponseReceived(Request request,
                    Response response) {

                System.out.println(response.getText() + "Response");

                if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                    Window.alert(response.getText());
                } else {
                    Window.alert(response.getText());
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i receive following error 
   com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestPermissionException: The URL http://gd.geobytes.com/gd?after=-1&variables=GeobytesCountry,GeobytesCity is invalid or violates the same-origin security restriction
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder.doSend(RequestBuilder.java:378)
    at com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder.sendRequest(RequestBuilder.java:254)
    at com.ip.client.IpAddressTest.onModuleLoad(IpAddressTest.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:369)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:185)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:380)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestException: (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI): Access to restricted URI denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Same Origin Policy" is something that browsers implement for the user's security. If you load javascrip code from one web site, that code can't start sending requests to other web sites. It can only send requests to the *same* site that the code came from.

More details available at [GWT docs](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/FAQ_SOP).

If you are in control of the server that serves the gwt javascript to the browser, you can have some code on that server that sends a request to gd.geobytes.com for you.

Answer (score 1):

We use  GWT for UI which is served by a Coldfusion server and started seeing this error in Hosted Mode.

Changing the Security Level to Medium-Low in the trusted sites zone in IE fixed it for me.

[image]